# IdeaPad 5 Touchpad unresponsive

Tags: arch-linux, mouse, touchpad, synaptic

I have been trying to diagnose my laptops trackpad which is not working. It is detected in xinput:

```
$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ USB Optical Mouse                         id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C           id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Ideapad extra buttons                     id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID events                          id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID 5 button array                  id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I have tried adding variations of the below commands to my kernal args:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="psmouse.synaptics_intertouch=0"
# psmouse.elantech_smbus=0"
# i8042.noloop i8042.nomux i8042.nopnp i8042.reset"
# i8042.nomux=1
```

The commented lines are previous attempts.

I think this is an elan touchpad from what I can tell, but if I run `dmesg | grep -i elan` it returns nothing.
I have both synaptic and libinput installed:

```
$ pacman -Ss libinput
extra/libinput 1.15.5-1 [installed]
    Input device management and event handling library
extra/xf86-input-libinput 0.29.0-2 (xorg-drivers) [installed]
    Generic input driver for the X.Org server based on libinput
$ pacman -Ss synaptics
extra/xf86-input-synaptics 1.9.1-1 (xorg-drivers) [installed]
    Synaptics driver for notebook touchpads
```

I do have an optical USB mouse plugged in which may be showing up here:

```
$ lsmod | grep mouse
mousedev               24576  0
```

and here:

```
$ cat /proc/bus/input/devices | grep touch -C 3 
$ cat /proc/bus/input/devices | grep mouse -C 3
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/0003:1BCF:0005.0001/input/input8
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event8 mouse0 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=17
B: KEY=1f0000 0 0 0 0
$ cat /proc/bus/input/devices | grep track -C 3
$
```

Otherwise I can't seem to find a trace of this touchpad. Any input is much appreciated, thanks.

```
$ cat /sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id/product_family
IdeaPad 5 14IIL05
$ uname -srvmpo
Linux 5.6.8-arch1-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed, 29 Apr 2020 16:22:56 +0000 x86_64 unknown GNU/Linux
```

#### UPDATE

I tried installing Windows + some Lenovo drivers and all of my hardware works as expected. I am going to try out some other kernel versions at the weekend and post my results.